# Do the number of entries per bin of a histogram obtained out of a try and reject sampling of a pdf follow a Poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution, monte-carlo

Imagine we have this pdf

$\frac{3}{8}(1+x^2)+0.017x$

defined in $x\in[-1,1]$. Imagine we make a try and reject sampling and get many values of $x$. Imagine that with this variables we make a histogram (which will reproduce more or less the shape of the pdf), of,say 1000 bins.

Imagine now that with the number of entries per bin we make another histogram. I have been told that this histogram will have the shape of a Poisson distribution but I cannot think why. So, is this true? Is this true for any initial pdf? and in the case it is true , why?

Comment: Is the original dataset finite?

Comment: If the number of bins is finite, this fit clashes with the infinite support of the Poisson distribution. Unless you mean the "Law of Small Numbers" which validates Poisson approximations for rare events.

Comment: @gung yes it is